# Using Mongo Aggregation to Get Distinct Values Based on Field

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework

So I have a collection called Cars that have some fields that are the same, but I want to be able to only get one of the documents based on that field.

```
[
  {
    _id:'12345',
    model:'Honda'
  },
  {
    _id:'12346',
    model:'Honda'
  },
  {
    _id:'12347',
    model:'Honda'
  },
  {
    _id:'12348',
    model:'Toyota'
  },
  {
    _id:'12349',
    model:'Volkswagen'
  },
  {
    _id:'12349',
    model:'Volkswagen'
  },
]
```

So here, I want to be able to get the distinct document based on the model field. I just want one document per model field.

Comment: you want to create a query  based on you choice?

Comment: Yes, an aggregation query

Answer (score 0):

first, you want to update mongoose v3 or up

the solution is to use the distinct function

```js
Cars.find().distinct('model', function(error, models) {});
```

I hope it will help you :)

Comment: This would only return a new object with the field though, but I want to be able to return the whole document.

Comment: i don't know if i wrong, but I mean the result of the whole function not the models perammater
`const cars = await Cars.find().distinct('model', function(error, models) {});`

Answer (score 0):

Use `$first` to pick a document in `$group` stage. Then do some wrangling with `$unwind` and `$replaceRoot` to retrieve the document.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$model",
      doc: {
        $first: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$doc"
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$doc"
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oqNcTGHMEvW) for your reference.

Comment: `$unwind` is not really needed here.